# How can I unpickle a subclass of 'dict' that validates with __setitem__ in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-3.3

I'm using python3.3. It's possible this problem doesn't exist in 2.x's pickle protocol, but I haven't actually verified.

Suppose I've created a `dict` subclass that counts every time a key is updated. Something like this:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(key, value, self.__dict__)
        if key == 'bar':
            self.counter += 1
        super(Foo, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

You might use it like this:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> assert f.counter == 0
>>> f['bar'] = 'baz'
... logging output...        
>>> assert f.counter == 1
```

Now let's pickle and unpickle it:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> f_str = pickle.dumps(f)
>>> f_new = pickle.loads(f_str)
bar baz {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 133, in __setitem__
    self.counter += 1
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'counter'
```

I think the `print()` in `__setitem__` shows the problem: `pickle.loads` attempts to write the dictionary's keys *before* it writes the object's attributes... at least I think that's what's happening. It's pretty easy to verify if you remove the `self.counter` reference in `Foo.__setitem__()`:

```
>>> f_mod = ModifiedFoo()
>>> f_mod['bar'] = 'baz'
>>> f_mod_str = pickle.dumps(f_mod)
>>> f_mod_new = pickle.loads(f_mod_str)
bar baz {}
>>> assert f_mod_new.counter == 0
>>>
```

Is this just a byproduct of the pickle protocol? I've tried variations on `__setstate__` to let it unpickle correctly, but as far as I can tell, it hits the `__setitem__` error before `__setstate__` is even called. Is there any way I can modify this object to allow unpickling?

Comment: I was having problems getting pickle to work correctly with `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` before too.  I don't remember the details of what I tracked down, but I ended up using `copy_reg.pickle` to register handlers for the object type, and that worked better for me.  Maybe you should take a look at the `copy_reg` module.

Comment: Ah, you are subclassing `dict`! That's where `__setstate__` is bypassed, because a *different* opcode is used to restore the contents of a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated by `pickle` documentation:

> When a pickled class instance is unpickled, its `__init__()` method is
>   normally *not* invoked.

In your case you *do* want to invoke `__init__`. However since your class is a new-style class you cannot use `__getinitargs__` (which isn't supported in python3 anyway). You could try to write your custom `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.counter, dict(self))
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.counter, data = state
        self.update(data)  # will *not* call __setitem__

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.counter += 1
        super(Foo, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

However this *still* doesn't work, because since you are subclassing `dict` and `dict` has a special handler for pickling, the `__getstate__` method *is* called, however the `__setstate__` method *is not*.

You can work around this defining the `__reduce__` method:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.counter, dict(self))
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.counter, data = state
        self.update(data)
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (Foo, (), self.__getstate__())

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.counter += 1
        super(Foo, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

Comment: Yet, if `__setstate__` is defined it should be called when building the class.

Comment: Those docs state it works for old-style classes, where this is a new style class, as far as I'm aware? I had tried [`__getnewargs__()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) but wasn't able to get traction. I was possibly misusing it. It looks like `__getinitargs__` doesn't exist in python3's docs.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, my answer isn't correct. Since you are subclassing `dict`, which has some special handling during pickling, what you want to achieve doesn't seem trivial. You'd better write a custom pickler/unpickler and register them via the `copy_reg` module.

Comment: @Christopher Never mind. Seems to be easy enough to define a `__reduce__` that works.

Comment: My preferred solution of the three, but I upvoted all of them as they're all valid, creative approaches to the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can add pickle support to your dictionary subclass by adding a [`__reduce__()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=__reduce__#object.__reduce__) method which will be used to get arguments to pass to a user defined function to reconstitute the object when it's unpickled.

Although, since your class is a`dict`subclass,  not wasn't quite as trivial to implement as I originally thought, but it's fairly simple once I figured out what needed to be done. Here's what I came up with — note that the `_Foo_unpickle_helper()` function can't be a regular or static method of the class, so that's why it's defined at the module level:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(key, value, self.__dict__)
        if key == 'bar':
            self.counter += 1
        super(Foo, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __reduce__(self):
        return _Foo_unpickle_helper, (self.counter, iter(self.items()))

def _Foo_unpickle_helper(counter, items):
    """ Reconstitute a Foo instance from the arguments. """
    foo = Foo()
    foo.counter = counter
    foo.update(items)  # apparently doesn't call __setitem__()...
    return foo

f = Foo()
f['bar'] = 'baz'
f['bar'] = 'baz'
print('f: {}'.format(f))
print('f.counter: {}'.format(f.counter))

import pickle
f_str = pickle.dumps(f)
print('----------')
f_new = pickle.loads(f_str)
print('f_new: {}'.format(f_new))
print('f_new.counter: {}'.format(f_new.counter))
```

Output:

```
bar baz {'counter': 0}
bar baz {'counter': 1}
f: {'bar': 'baz'}
f.counter: 2
----------
f_new: {'bar': 'baz'}
f_new.counter: 2
```

Comment: This won't restore the counter if you *replace* the value of a key; `f['bar'] = 'baz'; f['bar'] = 'foo'` would leave the counter set to `2`, but your code restores it to `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You are subclassing `dict`, and the pickle protocol will use the dedicated `dict` handler to store the keys and values in the resulting pickle data, using a *different* set of opcodes to restore these to your object again.

As a result, `__setstate__` is going only going to be called *after* restoring the dictionary keys, and the state contains only the `counter` attribute.

There are two work-arounds here:

1. Make your `counter` code resilient in the face of `__init__` not being called:

   ```
   class Foo(dict):
       counter = 0

       def __setitem__(self, key, value):
           print(key, value, self.__dict__)
           if key == 'bar':
               self.counter += 1
           super(Foo, self).__setitem__(key, value)
   ```

   Here `counter` is a class attribute and thus always present. You could also use:

   ```
   self.counter = getattr(self, 'counter', 0) + 1
   ```

   to ensure there is a default value for the missing attribute.
2. Provide a `__newargs__` method; it can return an empty tuple, but specifying it ensures that `__new__` is called when unpickling, which in turn could call `__init__`:

   ```
   class Foo(dict):
       def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
           f = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
           f.__init__()
           return f

       def __init__(self):
           self.counter = 0

       def __setitem__(self, key, value):
           print(key, value, self.__dict__)
           if key == 'bar':
               self.counter += 1
           super(Foo, self).__setitem__(key, value)

       def __getnewargs__(self):
           # Call __new__ (and thus __init__) on unpickling.
           return ()
   ```

   Note that after `__init__` is called, the unpickler still will set all the keys, *then* restore `__dict__`. `self.counter` will reflect the correct value in the end.

Demos:

1st approach:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> class Foo(dict):
...     counter = 0
...     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
...         print(key, value, self.__dict__)
...         if key == 'bar':
...             self.counter += 1
...         super(Foo, self).__setitem__(key, value)
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f['bar'] = 'baz'
bar baz {}
>>> f.counter
1
>>> f['bar'] = 'foo'
bar foo {'counter': 1}
>>> f.counter
2
>>> f_str = pickle.dumps(f)
>>> new_f = pickle.loads(f_str)
bar foo {}
>>> new_f.counter
2
>>> new_f.items()
dict_items([('bar', 'foo')])
```

2nd approach:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> class Foo(dict):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
...         f = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
...         f.__init__()
...         return f
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.counter = 0
...     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
...         print(key, value, self.__dict__)
...         if key == 'bar':
...             self.counter += 1
...         super(Foo, self).__setitem__(key, value)
...     def __getnewargs__(self):
...         return ()
... 

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f['bar'] = 'baz'
bar baz {'counter': 0}
>>> f.counter
1
>>> f['bar'] = 'foo'
bar foo {'counter': 1}
>>> f.counter
2
>>> f_str = pickle.dumps(f)
>>> new_f = pickle.loads(f_str)
bar foo {}
>>> new_f.counter
2
>>> new_f.items()
dict_items([('bar', 'foo')])
```

Comment: Note that the second solution doesn't preserve `counter`. After unpickling you'll always have `counter == len(foo)` which need not be true before the pickling.

Comment: @Bakuriu: No, it *does* preserve `counter`, because `counter` attribute will be set *after* the keys are set.

Comment: In any case I just tried and adding `__getnewargs__` does *not* call `__init__`. I still get an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: This is Python 3; I tested it in 3.3.2, and this *works*.

Comment: @Bakuriu: ick, I left another experiment in place; make `counter` use a `getattr()` call. My mistake, updating.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Indeed, calling `Foo.__new__(Foo)` directly doesn't call `__init__`; you'd have to do so explicitly. Humbug.

Comment: It doesn't seem that the presence of `__getnewargs__` affects whether or not `__new__` is called, at least in python 3.6. I just posted a [documentation issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue29597) about it.