# Can't save and load a custom dict object I implemented

Tags: python, dictionary, inheritance, pickle, super

I have a custom dictionary I implemented for my problem.
I reduced the code to the minimum required code to reproduce the problem.
here is the code

```
import pickle

class ItemToIndexMappings(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ItemToIndexMappings, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.default_value = 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in super().keys():
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
            if value >= self.default_value:
                self.default_value = value + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = ItemToIndexMappings()
    obj["a"] = 1

    with open("someFilename", 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f)

    with open("someFilename", "rb") as f:
        obj2 = pickle.load(f)
```

When trying to load the object, I get the error
`AttributeError: 'ItemToIndexMappings' object has no attribute 'default_value'`

After some tries, I managed to see that if I'm not using `super().__setitem__(key, value)` in my `__setitem__` method, the problem is solved.

Any tips on how to save this special dict?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand : is there an issue with your implementation, or are you looking for ideas on how to save your object in a peristent file without using the pickling module ? For me your implementation works fine.

Comment: @SpaceBurger Were you able to run this code? it does not give you the error? I tried sending this to several friends, but the error reproduced for all of them.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked duplicate fixes the problem.   Another approach, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21145612/5320906), would be to add `self.__dict__.setdefault('default_value', 0)` or similar before the `if value >= self.default_value` statement in `__setitem__.